# Rust, make a closure inside a closure avoiding "closure may outlive the current function"

Tags: rust, closures, borrow

I'm trying to write a function to transform a data structure in the form:

```
input = [("a", [1,2,3]), ("b", [4,5,6])]
```

Into

```
output = [(a,1), (c,2) ..... (b,6)]
```

My code is currently this:

```
    let foo=vec![('a', vec![1,2,3]), ('v', vec![2,3,4])];
    let baz: Vec<(char,i32)> = foo.into_iter().map(|a|a.1.into_iter().map( |b|(a.0, b))).flatten().collect();
    println!("{:?}",baz);
```

I'm getting this error:

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `a`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/lib.rs:10:76
   |
10 |     let baz: Vec<(char,i32)> = foo.into_iter().map(|a|a.1.into_iter().map( |b|(a.0, b))).flatten().collect();
   |                                                                            ^^^ - `a` is borrowed here
   |                                                                            |
   |                                                                            may outlive borrowed value `a`
   |
note: closure is returned here
  --> src/lib.rs:10:55
   |
10 |     let baz: Vec<(char,i32)> = foo.into_iter().map(|a|a.1.into_iter().map( |b|(a.0, b))).flatten().collect();
   |                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `a` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
10 |     let baz: Vec<(char,i32)> = foo.into_iter().map(|a|a.1.into_iter().map( move |b|(a.0, b))).flatten().collect();
   |                                                                            ^^^^^^^^

error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `a`
  --> src/lib.rs:10:76
   |
10 |     let baz: Vec<(char,i32)> = foo.into_iter().map(|a|a.1.into_iter().map( |b|(a.0, b))).flatten().collect();
   |                                                       ---                  ^^^ - borrow occurs due to use in closure
   |                                                       |                    |
   |                                                       value moved here     value borrowed here after partial move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `a.1` has type `std::vec::Vec<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I think this means that Rust doesn't know how to copy my vector of i32s, so thinks it must move the vec instead, but cannot do it.

How do I fix this problem? Implement a Copy method for vec, or is there a niftier way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand how you get (c,2) from the input.  Did you mean to say
`output = [(a,1), (a,2) ... (b,6)]`?  And did you mean for the "a" and "b" to be single-quoted, as they are in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IntoIterator` consumes and yields values. Since `Vec` doesn’t implement `Copy`, when you call `a.1.into_iter()`, it is moved. You can clone it like this: `a.1.clone().into_iter()`

Also, you want to use the `move` keyword to take the ownership of `a` in the closure.

```rust
let baz: Vec<(char, i32)> = foo
    .into_iter()
    .map(|a| a.1.clone().into_iter().map(move |b| (a.0, b)))
    .flatten()
    .collect();
println!("{:?}", baz);
// [('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3), ('v', 2), ('v', 3), ('v', 4)]
```

Answer (score 4):

When you call `a.1.into_iter()`, `a` is moved, and can't be borrowed in the inner closure anymore.

The easiest solution is to destructure `a`, so each component can be borrowed/moved individually:

```rust
.map(|(c, v)| v.into_iter().map(move |b| (c, b)))
```

Also note the `move` keyword, which means that `c` is moved into the inner closure, so it's allowed to outlive the outer closure.