# Segregated copy for nested closures

Tags: rust, closures, ownership

I looked for similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61002805/rust-make-a-closure-inside-a-closure-avoiding-closure-may-outlive-the-current) but it seems they are always different enough. I'm trying to compile (a more complex version of) this piece of code:

```
let vec: Vec<f64> = ⋯;
let length = ⋯;
let iterator = (0usize..length)
    .flat_map(|i| (0usize..length).map(|j| vec[(i + j) % vec.len()]));
```

but I get this ownership error:

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `i`, which is owned by the current function
  --> tests\test.rs:19:45
   |
19 |         .flat_map(|i| (0usize..length).map(|j| vec[(i + j) % vec.len()]));
   |                                            ^^^      - `i` is borrowed here
   |                                            |
   |                                            may outlive borrowed value `i`
   |
```

I do not want to take ownership of `vec` so none of my closures should be `move`. It seems to me that theoretically `i` could be copied inside `(0usize..length).map(|j| vec[(i + j) % vec.len()])` but because of `vec` it is only borrowed. As far as I know it may not be possible to tell rustc to borrow some variables and to copy others (Or is it?)

Changing the inner closure to `(0usize..length).map(|j| vec[(i + j) % vec.len()]).collect::<Vec<_>>()` solves the issue. Unfortunately it implies multiple memory allocation I would like to avoid as they seem totally unnecessary.

As a clarification this example is intended to be generated by a macro. In the general case it may generate an arbitrary number of nested levels and involve an arbitrary number of vectors to borrow:

```
let vec: Vec<f64> = ⋯;
let vec2: Vec<Vec<Vec<f64>>> = ⋯;
let length = ⋯;
let iterator = (0usize..length)
    .flat_map(|i| (0usize..length)
        .flat_map(|j| (0usize..length)
            .map(|k| vec[(i + j + k) % vec.len()] + vec2[i][j][k]));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `move` to avoid the issue with `i`. If you don't want to move the vec into the closure, you can take a reference to it first and move *that* into the closure:

```
let iterator = (0usize..length)
    .flat_map (|i| {
        let vec = &vec[..];
        (0usize..length).map(move |j| vec[(i + j) % vec.len()])
    });
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=53addd1aac0e04c96769fdea4521c4a2)

Comment: This works indeed. Actually I have also found another strategy: spliting the closure between one that moves and the other that borrows: `(0usize..length).flat_map(|i| (0usize..length).map(move|j| (i, j))).map(|(i, j)| vec[(i + j) % vec.len()])`